# Python. Issue with pandas source code. How to tread it?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting a strange issue with one of pandas functions (it is in python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py). This code fragment is self explanatory:

```
def _format_argument_list(allow_args: list[str]):

    # If I add this print, the function works in 100% of cases. If I remove(comment) it, it fails in 100% of cases with 
    #print(f"allow_args is {allow_args}")
    if "self" in allow_args:
        allow_args.remove("self")
    if not allow_args:
        return ""
    elif len(allow_args) == 1:
        return f" except for the argument '{allow_args[0]}'"
    else:
        # Next line of code is failing
        last = allow_args[-1]
        args = ", ".join("'" + x + "'" for x in allow_args[:-1])
        return f" except for the arguments {args} and '{last}'"
```

The failing message is:

```
last = allow_args[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So the only difference between 100% fail and 100% pass is just a debug print and it seems strange. Is there any rational way to explain it or should I treat it as an interpreter bug? I use nogil-3.9.10 fork. If I disable multi threading in the project, it works finely.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you pass as an parameter for allow_args. If I do `_format_argument_list(["one", "two", "three"])` it works fine

Comment: An example of allow_args is `['self', 'value']`. If I do not print it in advance, it will fail.